# Powershell en C#, Obtengo diferentes respuestas desde el mismo Powershell que desde mi codigo en C#

Tags: c#, powershell

Estoy intentando ejecutar un script de powershell en mi codigo C#. Para esto utilizo la version de Microsoft.Powershell.SDK 7.2.0-preview en .net 5.0 y con Microsoft Visual Estudio 2019. Estoy realizando una app de escritorio. El problema es que desde el mismo powershell, el script me produce una buena respuesta. Pero cuando lo ejecuto en C# obtengo una respuesta incompleta.

Lo que obtengo ejecutando en powershell:

San Luis Ctv S.A.|190......|Wiber Fibra ??ptica|[233.8906 km]|(11.75 ms)|2.82|0.58

En C#:

San Luis Ctv S.A.|190......|Telecom Argentina|[233.8906 km]|(0 ms)|2.82|

Aqui les dejo mi script que busca calcular la banda ancha, en la respuesta de C# no consigo obtener la subida, todo el resto de los datos llegan correctamente pero si lo ejecuto en powershell funciona correctamente.

```
function Start-SpeedTest
{
    Param(
        [Parameter()]
        [ValidateRange(1,30)]
        [Double]$UploadMB = "7.5",
        [ValidateRange(1,30)]
        [Double]$DownloadMB = "7.5"
    )

    # Server distance helper function
    function Get-ServerInfo {
   
        param(
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
            $servers
        )
         
        foreach($server in $servers)
        {
            $radius = 6371
            [float]$dlat = ([float]$orilat - [float]$server.lat) * 3.14 / 180
            [float]$dlon = ([float]$orilon - [float]$server.lon) * 3.14 / 180
            [float]$a = [math]::Sin([float]$dlat/2) * [math]::Sin([float]$dlat/2) + [math]::Cos([float]$orilat * 3.14 / 180 ) * [math]::Cos([float]$server.lat * 3.14 / 180 ) * [math]::Sin([float]$dlon/2) * [math]::Sin([float]$dlon/2)
            [float]$c = 2 * [math]::Atan2([math]::Sqrt([float]$a ), [math]::Sqrt(1 - [float]$a))
            [float]$d = [float]$radius * [float]$c

            New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                Distance = $d
                Country = $server.country
                Sponsor = $server.sponsor
                Url = $server.url
                Host = $server.host
            }
        }
    }

    # Avg Ping response helper function
    function Get-AvgPing {  
        param(
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
            $servers
        )

        foreach ($server in $servers) {
     
            try {
                #c# Write-Verbose "Testing ping to $server"
                $test = (Test-Connection -ComputerName $server -Count 4 -ErrorAction Stop | measure-Object -Property ResponseTime -Average).average
                $response = ($test -as [decimal] )
            }  
            catch [System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingException] {
                #c# Write-Warning "$server is offline."
            }
            catch {
                #c# Write-Warning "Ping test failed for $server"
            }  
            finally {
                New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                    'Destination' = $server
                    'Avg' = $response
                }    
                #c# Write-Verbose "$response ms average ping to $server"
            }
        }
    }
   
    # Download Test helper function
    function Get-DataWCAsync{
        param(
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
            $Url,
            [switch]$IncludeStats,
            [ValidateRange(1,30)]
            [Double]$DownloadMB = "7.5"
        )
        $global:download = ($DownloadMB * 1mb)
        $global:wc = New-Object Net.WebClient
        $wc.UseDefaultCredentials = $false
        $wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        $wc.Headers.Add("Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*")
        $wc.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0;Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)")
        $wc.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
        $wc.Headers.Add("Referer", "http://www.speedtest.net")
        $start = Get-Date
        $null = Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $wc -EventName DownloadProgressChanged -MessageData @{start=$start;includeStats=$includestats} -SourceIdentifier WebClient.DownloadProgressChanged -Action {
            filter Get-FileSize {
                "{0:N2} {1}" -f $(
                    if ($_ -lt 1kb) { $_, 'Bytes' }
                    elseif ($_ -lt 1mb) { ($_/1kb), 'KB' }
                    elseif ($_ -lt 1gb) { ($_/1mb), 'MB' }
                    elseif ($_ -lt 1tb) { ($_/1gb), 'GB' }
                    elseif ($_ -lt 1pb) { ($_/1tb), 'TB' }
                    else { ($_/1pb), 'PB' }
                )
            }
            $time = ((Get-Date) - $event.MessageData.start)
            $averagespeed = ($eventargs.BytesReceived * 8 / 1MB) / $time.TotalSeconds
            $elapsed = $Time.ToString('hh\:mm\:ss')
            $remainingseconds = ($eventargs.TotalBytesToReceive - $eventargs.BytesReceived) * 8 / 1MB / $averagespeed
            $receivedsize = $eventargs.BytesReceived | Get-FileSize
            $received = $eventargs.BytesReceived
            $totalSize = $download | Get-FileSize
            $percent = $eventargs.BytesReceived / $download * 100
            $percent = [Math]::Round($percent)  
           
            If ($received -ge $download) {
                $wc.CancelAsync()
            }
                         
            Write-Progress -Activity (" $url {0:N2} Mbps" -f $averagespeed) -Status ("{0} of {1} ({2}% in {3})" -f $receivedSize,$totalsize,$percent,$elapsed) -SecondsRemaining $remainingseconds -PercentComplete $percent
            if ($percent -eq 100){
                Write-Progress -Activity (" $url {0:N2} Mbps" -f $averagespeed) -Status 'Done' -Completed
               
                if ($event.MessageData.includeStats.IsPresent){
                    $global:down = [Math]::Round($averageSpeed, 2)
                }
            }
        }    
        $null = Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $wc -EventName DownloadDataCompleted -SourceIdentifier WebClient.DownloadDataCompleted -Action {
            Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier WebClient.DownloadProgressChanged
            Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier WebClient.DownloadDataCompleted
        }
   
        try  {  
            #c# Write-Verbose "Performing download from $url"
            $wc.DownloadDataAsync($url)  
        }  
        catch [System.Net.WebException]  {  
            #c# Write-Warning "Download of $url failed"  
        }  
        finally  {    
            while ($wc.IsBusy) {}
            $wc.Dispose()
        }  
    }
   
    # Upload Test helper function
    function Push-DataWCAsync{
        param(
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
            $url,
            $byteArray,
            [switch]$includeStats
        )
        $wc = New-Object Net.WebClient
        $wc.UseDefaultCredentials = $false
        $wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        $wc.Headers.Add("Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*")
        $wc.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0;Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)")
        $wc.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
        $wc.Headers.Add("Referer", "http://www.speedtest.net")
        $start = Get-Date
        $null = Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $wc -EventName UploadProgressChanged -MessageData @{start=$start;includeStats=$includeStats} -SourceIdentifier WebClient.UploadProgressChanged -Action {
            filter Get-FileSize {
                "{0:N2} {1}" -f $(
                    if ($_ -lt 1kb) { $_, 'Bytes' }
                    elseif ($_ -lt 1mb) { ($_/1kb), 'KB' }
                    elseif ($_ -lt 1gb) { ($_/1mb), 'MB' }
                    elseif ($_ -lt 1tb) { ($_/1gb), 'GB' }
                    elseif ($_ -lt 1pb) { ($_/1tb), 'TB' }
                    else { ($_/1pb), 'PB' }
                )
            }
           
            $Time = ((Get-Date) - $event.MessageData.start)
            $averageSpeed = ($eventargs.BytesSent * 8 / 1MB) / $Time.TotalSeconds
            $elapsed = $Time.ToString('hh\:mm\:ss')
            $remainingSeconds = ($eventargs.TotalBytesToSend - $eventargs.BytesSent) * 8 / 1MB / $averageSpeed
            $receivedSize = $eventargs.BytesSent | Get-FileSize
            $totalSize = $eventargs.TotalBytesToSend | Get-FileSize  
            $percent = $eventargs.BytesSent / $eventargs.TotalBytesToSend * 100
            $percent = [Math]::Round($percent)  
                       
            Write-Progress -Activity (" $url {0:N2} Mbps" -f $averageSpeed) -Status ("{0} of {1} ({2}% in {3})" -f $receivedSize,$totalSize,$percent,$elapsed) -SecondsRemaining $remainingSeconds -PercentComplete $percent
            if ($eventargs.ProgressPercentage -eq 100){
                Write-Progress -Activity (" $url {0:N2} Mbps" -f $averageSpeed) -Status 'Done' -Completed
               
                if ($event.MessageData.includeStats.IsPresent){
                    $global:upload = [Math]::Round($averageSpeed, 2)
                }
            }
        }    
        # $null = Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $wc -EventName UploadDataCompleted -SourceIdentifier WebClient.UploadDataCompleted -Action {
        # Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier WebClient.UploadProgressChanged -Force
        # Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier WebClient.UploadDataCompleted -Force
        # }
       
        try  {  
            #c# Write-Verbose "Performing upload to $url"
            $wc.UploadDataAsync($url,'POST',$byteArray)
        }  
        catch [System.Net.WebException]  {  
            #c# Write-Warning "Upload of $url failed"  
        }  
        finally  {
            while ($wc.IsBusy) {}  
            $wc.Dispose()  
            Remove-Job * -Force
        }
    }
   
    #c# Write-Output 'Retrieving configuration...'

    $uri = 'http://beta.speedtest.net/speedtest-config.php'
    try {
        [xml]$config = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -UseBasicParsing -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    catch {
        #c# Write-Error "Could not download configuration from $uri"
        Break
    }

    $ip = $config.settings.client.ip
    $isp = $config.settings.client.isp
    #c# Write-Output "Testing from $isp ($ip)"

    $orilat = $config.settings.client.lat
    $orilon = $config.settings.client.lon

    #c# Write-Output 'Retrieving server list...'

    $uri = 'http://www.speedtest.net/speedtest-servers.php'
    try {
        [xml]$hosts = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -UseBasicParsing -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    catch {
        #c# Write-Error "Could not download server list from $uri"
        Break
    }

    #c# Write-Output 'Selecting best server...'

    $servers = $hosts.settings.servers.server
       
    # Sort the distance of each server
    $closestserver = Get-ServerInfo -Servers $servers | Sort-Object -Property distance
   
    $servers = $closestserver[0],$closestserver[1],$closestserver[2]
    $serverurlspilt = ($servers).host -split ':8080'
    $servers = $serverurlspilt[0],$serverurlspilt[2],$serverurlspilt[4]
   
    # Get avg ping response
    $bestserver = Get-AvgPing -servers $servers

    # Getting lazy and just want lowest latency server asap
    $index = 0
    $minvalue = [decimal]::MaxValue
    $bestserver.avg | ForEach-Object { if ($minvalue -gt $_) {$minvalue = $_; $minindex = $index}; $index++ }
     
    $location = $closestserver[$index].sponsor
    $distance = $closestserver[$index].distance
    #c# Write-Output "Hosted by $location [$distance km] ($minvalue ms)"

    $serverurlspilt = ($closestserver[$index]).url -split 'upload'
    $url = $serverurlspilt[0] + "random4000x4000.jpg"

 #c# Write-Output 'Testing download speed...'
    Get-DataWCAsync -Url $url -DownloadMB $downloadmb -IncludeStats
     
    if ($down -eq $null) {
    #c# Write-Output "Oh no, we couldn't calculate download average"
}
    else {
        #c# Write-Output "Download: $down Mbps"
    }
   
    # Creating a random byte array to avoid bad download data messing with the upload
    $bytearray = New-Object Byte[] ($uploadmb * 1mb)
    (New-Object Random).NextBytes($bytearray)
   
    $url = ($closestserver[$index]).url
    #c# Write-Output 'Testing upload speed...'
    Push-DataWCAsync -Url $url -byteArray $bytearray -IncludeStats        

    if ($upload -eq $null) {
    #c# Write-Output "Oh no, we couldn't calculate upload average"
}
    else {
        #c# Write-Output "Upload: $upload Mbps"
    }


    #c# Write-Output 'Tests Completed'    
return "$isp|($ip)|$location|[$distance km]|($minvalue ms)|$down|$upload"

}

Start-SpeedTest
```

Y aqui lo llamo

```
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
            ps.AddScript(File.ReadAllText(@"..\..\..\Resources\start_speedtest.ps1"));
            Collection<PSObject> PSOutput = ps.Invoke();
            string retorno_completo = "";
            string[] retorno = null;
            foreach (PSObject outputItem in PSOutput)
            {
                if (outputItem != null)
                {
                    retorno_completo = outputItem.BaseObject.ToString();
                    retorno = retorno_completo.Split("|");
                }
            }
            string[] resultado = new string[2]; ;
            if (retorno != null)
            {
                resultado[0] = retorno[5];
                resultado[1] = retorno[6];
            }
            

            return resultado;
```

Utilizo la version de Microsoft.Powershell.SDK 7.2.0-preview.2

Comment: Y está cierto que el script de arriba está en ..\\..\\..\\Resources\\start_speedtest.ps1 ?  (A propósito, puede evitar los \\ por añadir @ antes del string, como @"..\..\..\Resources\start_speedtest.ps1")

Comment: Sisi, porque lo esta ejecutando, solo que la respuesta es incompleta. Si la descarga la puedo obtener sin problemas, es mas todos los datos que retorna el script menos la subida. Ademas si ejecuto el script en el mismo PowerShell si obtengo la subida con el mismo script. Gracias por lo del arroba, no lo sabia jaja